# jeditable datepicker save $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using Jeditable datepicker, it displays well, no problems, it works. But I don't know how to catch the $_POST. Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
var date = $( '.editable' );
  date.editable(
    function( value, settings ) {
      date.html( value );
    },
    {
        type: 'datepicker',
        datepicker: {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-70:-15",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
      }
    }
  );
} );
```

Where do I have to specify the php file that catches the response? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using `AJAX` or anything else to send the data to your data base if so show that code too please.

Comment: thank you for the response. I included the jquery and the jeditable class. I managed to send the content of the other text fields specifying the path at the beginning of the function (something like this `$('.edit').editable ('update_element.php', {maxlenght: 20, submit: "Ok" ` etc.)
But I cannot figure out where to specify the same file in the example above. Thanks again.